# Is it possible to put a background color on top of another background color?

Tags: html, css

I've just started getting into HTML & CSS, I've only been learning for a week or so but I'm working on a project right now and I wanted to know if it's possible to put a background color on top of another background color. [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFQfe.png)

I've been trying to achieve something like this however to no avail, here's what I got:

```
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body::before {
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have to use different div tag or span tag and place it like image to achieve that.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/yajoyapava/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, `background-color` is at the very bottom of the stack, and on top of it, [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) is drawn. We can use a [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) to simulate a solid color.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray; /* this is painted at the bottom of the stack */

  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black); /* this is painted over the background-color */
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Also **`background-size` only works with `background-image`**, not `background-color`.

And since, `background-image` can have multiple values (separated by comma), you can layer as many backgrounds as you want, as you can see in this example:

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(lightgrey, lightgrey),
    linear-gradient(black, black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50px;
  background-position: 
     0 50px,
     0 0;
}
```

In the code, I added another black background using `linear-gradient()` and layered it on top of the existing `lightgray` one. The last entry in the `background-image` property will end up at the top of the stack.

You will also notice that `background-position` can have multiple values. In fact, `background-size` can have multiple values to. And each value corresponds to the `background-image` (meaning the first `background-position` will apply to the first entry on the `background-image`, the second one will apply to the second entry on the `background-image`, etc.).

You can play around this code [here](https://codepen.io/maniczirconium/pen/QWNbaKx).